# Disable Drag and Drop in CHtmlEditCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I am using CHtmlEditCtrl to implement a simple Html Editor.

I want to prevent user from Drag & Dropping any content onto it, because it replaces existing content with the dropped content.

I tried calling RevokeDragDrop, but it does not work, since the Wrapper itself is not registered for Drag and Drop.

Any idea how can I block or intercept the Drag and Drop events?

I am using MFC in VC++ 2010.

Comment: Try handling and cancellig [ondrop event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536929(v=vs.85).aspx) on the `body` element. You can get it via `IHTMLDocument2::get_body`.

Comment: I haven't managed capturing the events in my code.
I created an IHTMLDocumentEvents2 Event sink and connected it in OnDocumentComplete, but none of my handlers is being fired.

Comment: Maybe I should add that the CHtmlEditCtrl is dynamically created and has no static ID which I could use for standard event capturing.

Comment: I wish I could help better, but my MFC knowledge is very rusty. You indeed would need to obtain the DOM `document` object and access its `body` when `document.readyState == 'complete'`.

Comment: That is one of the events I can react upon. Like mentioned above, I already do some stuff in OnDocumentComplete. I will try to bind the body events there. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Another option might be to override MFC implementation of [IDocHostUIHandler::GetDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753255(v=vs.85).aspx) and return NULL for `ppDropTarget`, if you find a way of doing it with MFC.